# Instance variable in private method is nil in the public controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a helper method to check if the logged in user is authorized to use certain functions, like `new`, `create`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy`.

This works when it gets to the view, but I want to block clever users from being able to create new `Games` by simply typing in the correct url.

In my controller I have:

```
before_action :is_admin, only: [:index, :platform, :publisher, :new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]

def destroy
  if !@admin
    @game.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to games_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  else
    redirect_to @game, notice: 'User not authorized to delete games.'
  end
end

def is_admin
  @admin = current_user.roles.detect {|r| r.name == "Super Admin" || r.name == "Game Admin"}
end
```

By using the debugger I can see that the private method is actually being called, but in the public methods `@admin` is null...

I suspect that this is because the instance variable is declared in the private space, but if it's available to the view, why is it not available to the controller...

Anyways, it anyone has any advice, or the correct way to do what I am trying to do, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think that `@admin` is being assigned a non-nil value by `is_admin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a better way, and it is now working. So for all of those stumbling upon this from google, here is what I did...

In my ApplicationController I created some new helper methods:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :current_user
  helper_method :is_super_admin
  helper_method :is_game_admin

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= Member.find(session[:member_id]) if session[:member_id]
  end

  def is_super_admin
    unless current_user.nil?
      current_user.roles.detect {|r| r.name == "Super Admin"} unless current_user.roles.nil?
    end
  end

  def is_game_admin
    unless current_user.nil?
      current_user.roles.detect {|r| r.name == "Game Admin"} unless current_user.roles.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

Then in the controller I want to restrict access to, I created a `before_action` that would get these values, then either show the action, or kick the user back to the index action...

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :is_admin, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]

  #... controller methods

  private

  def is_admin
    unless is_super_admin || is_game_admin
      redirect_to games_url, notice: 'User is not authorized to perform this function.'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to cache `@admin` as `current_user` has already been cached. Or if current_user is not cached, there is no need to cache admin as well.

Based on current code, a simpler method to check role is to set it model level

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def admin?
    role.match /admin/i
  end
end
```

Then in controller

```
def destroy
  if current_user.admin?
    # other code
  end
  # other code
end
```

Comment: This looks like a much better way to handle it, thank you. But, where can I find documentation on the `match` method.

Comment: @SnareChops, the method would be okay if you want to use it once and differentiate admin only, for more rules it's better to check CanCan. For match doc, here you are: http://apidock.com/ruby/String/match

Comment: I just noticed your role is not a field in User table but another one so the specific code needs to change according to your setting. Anyway the principle is the same, such job should be done in model level.

Comment: Yeah, since users can have more than one role, and a role can have more than one user, I created a many-many relationship for flexibility.